# jstree how to open a node

Tags: jquery, jstree

how to refresh the tree and select the selected node before moving, where moving happend in backup.I use the code like `$.jstree._reference("#orgTree").open_node("#" + parentNode.attr("id"))`, but it seems does not work, help thanks

Comment: Can you post a demo of the web page (in its current state) so that we can figure out the problem more easily?

Comment: This Google search query might be helpful: https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=jstree+open+node&oq=jstree+open&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l4.672.2823.0.4150.11.11.0.0.0.0.225.1013.10j0j1.11.0.epsugrpqhmsignedin%2Chtma%3D120%2Chtmb%3D120..0.0.0..1.1.17.psy-ab.1QUE_LfKFPM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.dmQ&fp=642a900480c7deed&biw=1366&bih=583